# Notify multiple times custom event to send email not working

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Having `obj` = the object that was `modified` and `SendNotificationEvent` a custom event I'm trying to notify the custom event something like:

```
for email in emails:
    notify(SendNotificationEvent(obj, email))
```

I have a custom content rule with send email action that sends the message on `SendNotificationEvent`.

The problem is **a single message is sent. The first one.** It seems notify is working a single time. Do you have any idea how to investigate and fix this issue?

I already tried with debugger here and it seems I can notify the event for other objects and the email is sent, but for each different obj a single one then nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This commit was very useful](https://github.com/eea/land.copernicus.content/commit/071df185efbe8c35991d45c2a4c98268a0bf8965). (Thank you, David, for nice description! Thank you, GitHub, for search feature.)

So, the solution is:

```
from plone.app.contentrules.handlers import close

for email in emails:
    evt = SendNotificationEvent(obj, email)
    notify(evt)
    close(evt)  # make sure it will work for multiple notify(
```